# Как записать условие для проверки значения из radio?

Tags: post, php, html, form

```
echo "<form action=' ' method='post' />
    Путин краб?
    <input type='radio' name='confirm' value='yes' />
    <input type='radio' name='confirm' value='no' checked='checked' /><br>
    <input type='submit'  value='выбрать' />
    </form>";
if(isset($_POST['confirn'=='yes'])) {
    echo 'верно';
} else {
    echo ' не верно';
}
```

Comment: надо было тебе в ответ постить

Comment: @нуб, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.

```
if(isset($_POST['confirm']) && $_POST['confirm'] =='yes')
```